# Using of matcher returns a must not be null

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mockito

I have this code

```
val record: LockDatabaseRecord = lockDatabaseRecordService.getTransLockDbRecord(dbRecordId) {
           it.lockDatabaseRecordKeys.size
}
```

And I try to mock it using ArgumentMatchers but I get this error

```
eq(lockId) must not be null
java.lang.NullPointerException: eq(lockId) must not be null
```

when using `eq` and `any(UUID::class.java) must not be null` when I use any.

This is how I mocked it

```
`when`(lockService.getTransLock(eq(lockId), any())).thenReturn(lock)
```

Let me know what I missed :(

Thank you!

Comment: Did you declare your `lockService` as Mock? Something like `val lockService = Mockito.mock(LockService::class.java)`

Comment: Hi! Yes I did.

    private val lockService: LockService = mock(LockService::class.java)

then I injected it in my function annotated with @BeforeEach
`
 @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        service = CommandService(lockService.....)
    }`

Comment: lockId is maybe null ?

Comment: Hi Ruokki. It is not null :( When I debug it, lockId has a value from `UUID.randomUUID()`

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that I need to use `mockito-kotlin` so this is my
`build.gradle` (I only imported mockito-inline)

```
    testImplementation 'org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:3.2.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.11.2'
```

And this is how I mocked it now

`whenever(lockService.getTransLock(eq(lockId), any())).thenReturn(lock)`